# Kotlin - preventing null returns for non-nullable generic functions

Tags: kotlin

I have the following method

```
fun <P> configure(property: KProperty1<R, P>, transform: (source: S) -> P) {
    ...
}
```

If I call this function with `Foo::bar` where `::bar` is non-nullable, the transform function allows me to return something that is nullable

```
configure(Foo::bar, { null })
```

Can the method be refactored to prevent the transform function from returning nullable results when the property is non-nullable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
fun <P> configure(...)
```

Try this

```
fun <P : Any> configure(...)
```

Because from the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints)

> The default upper bound (if none specified) is Any?

Comment: That doesn't work if `::bar` _is_ nullable. And doesn't solve the actual problem even if it isn't, because it isn't limited to nullability :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually more general:

```
configure(Foo::bar, { Object() })
```

will work too. Because `KProperty1` is [covariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) in its second type parameter, a `KProperty1<R, String>` (for example) is also a `KProperty1<R, String?>`, a `KProperty1<R, CharSequence>`, etc. This also applies to function type `(source: S) -> P`. So whatever (single-parameter) `transform` you pass, the compiler will always find a `P` such that the types fit: the least upper bound of the property's and the function's return types.

One rather ugly workaround I can think of is creating a non-covariant wrapper type:

```
class NonCov<A>(val value: A)

fun <P> configure(property: NonCov<KProperty1<R, P>>, transform: NonCov<(source: S) -> P)>) {
    ... // use property.value and transform.value
}
```

Then

```
class A(val x: String)

fun <P> configure(property: NonCov<kotlin.reflect.KProperty1<A, P>>, transform: NonCov<(source: A) -> P>) {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    configure(NonCov(A::x), NonCov { "" }) // compiles
    configure(NonCov(A::x), NonCov { null }) // doesn't compile
}
```